# Adding fixed backoff for reconnection attempt in JmsOutBoundGatway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, ibm-mq, message-queue, spring-jms

How can i add max attempts for connection retry for message consumer using jmsOutboundGateway?I am using ibm mq. below is the configuration

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway request-channel="defaultSerializedRequestChannel" reply-channel="defaultDeserializedResponseChannel"
                                                                 requires-reply="true" correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
                                                                 request-destination-name="${fbu.request.key.management.queue}"
                                                                 reply-destination-name="${fbu.response.key.management.queue}"
                                                                 receive-timeout="150000"
                                                                 connection-factory="keyManagementConnectionFactory">

            <int-jms:reply-listener recovery-interval="${mq.connection.recovery.interval}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no such an option on that `keyManagementConnectionFactory`, then you can try to use a `<request-handler-advice-chain>` with the `<retry-advice>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: I tried <request-handler-advice-chain>, but it's not working. And in the connection factory there is no such option. We can add one in container factory though. But there is no option to set container factory in outbound gatway